# How can i display all the values in a textbox? there are more values

Tags: c#

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument(); 

 xmlDoc.Load(file);

  XmlNodeList name = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Name");

  XmlNodeList description = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Description");

XmlNodeList synonymname = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Synonym_Name");

 XmlNodeList typeflag = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Type_Flag");

XmlNodeList loopflag = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Loop_Flag");          

XmlNodeList pacgroups = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Pac_Groups");            

XmlNodeList grouid = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Grou_Id");

XmlNodeList funcid = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Func_Id");
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which values do you want to display? All the node values? Are you sure you want to use a `TextBox` and not a `TextArea`?

Comment: Can you show us your input `Xml` format?

Comment: Ye i want all the node values, but i dont know how should i do that

Comment: Typically you would create a textbox for each node or concatenate all your results to show in only one textbox.

Comment: i did it like this
 textBox1.Text = "name:" + name[0].InnerText + "\r\n" + "description: "+
                    description[0].InnerText ;
is this very bad, or does it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodeNames = new [] { "Name", "Description", "Synonym_Name" };

var nodeContents = nodeNames
                       .Select(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName)
                       .Select(_ => _.Cast<XmlNode>())
                       .SelectMany(_ => _)
                       .Select(node => 
                       {
                            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true };

                            using (var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create(stringBuilder, settings))
                            {
                                node.WriteTo(writer);

                                writer.Flush();

                                return stringBuilder.ToString();
                            }
                        });

var box = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBox();

box.Text = string.Concat(nodeContents);
```